# CryptoAPI wrapped keys

Tags: cryptography, c++

With CryptoAPI, is there a way to decrypt (*using CryptDecrypt*) a key written into a SYMMETRICWRAPKEYBLOB?
In my c++ program, i wrap a symmetric key *k1* with another symmetric key *k2* into a symmetric key blob. I have a third key, *k3*, equal to *k2* but with a different handle. My goal is to decrypt the blob with this key. I have already did it using a SIMPLEBLOB and a public key.
Thanks in advance for your attention.
Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379931%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation you link to says, the format used for SYMMETRICWRAPKEYBLOB follows [RFC 3217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3217). It is a weird format in which the data is encrypted, then *reversed* (last byte becomes first, and so on), and then encrypted *again*. Both encryptions use CBC. If you want to do it by hand, instead of using [CryptImportKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380207%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then you will have to follow RFC 3217, with two calls to `CryptDecrypt()`, and your code will also have to do the byte reversal and the rest of the packaging.

Alternatively, import the key blob with `CryptImportKey()`, then export it again by encrypting with an *asymmetric* (RSA) key of your own, which you can then decrypt. At some point, Microsoft themselves were documenting that, in order to export a symmetric key "as is", the best way was to call `CryptExportKey()` with a handcrafted RSA public key with a public exponent equal to 1, i.e. not really a *correct* RSA key -- with such a public exponent, RSA encryption is mostly a no-operation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'll try to use the RSA public key with exponent 1 as you suggested, then I'll give you a feedback.